# Pointer to a object that scoping in the function

Tags: c++, function, pointers, reference

I just think of a question about pointer,
the pointer p first initial in main function and point to object "a"
and then call function f , and change to point object "b".
but the scope of "b" is only in function. After call the function f, why the pointer p is still pointer to "a". Shouldn't p be NULL or something else?

```
 void f(int*p){
    int b = 10;
    p = &b;
}
int main(){

    int*p1 = NULL;
    int a=6;
    p1 = &a;
    f(p1);
    cout<<*p1<<endl;//output 6
    cout<<a<<endl;//output 6
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, and that's why pointers are dangerous ;-)

Comment: See : http://ideone.com/0CNFdp
and observe the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens:

Because you pass pointer *by value*, a local copy is created in function `f`, Then you assign another value (pointer to b) to that copy and leave the function. Original pointer remains unchanged.

Now let's suppose, that you modify the function in the following way:

```
void f(int * & p){
    int b = 10;
    p = &b;
}
```

**Don't do this at home!**

Now, the actual pointer is passed to function, no copy is created. Then a pointer to b is assigned to it and function returns. 
Then you try to access the value pointed to by `p1` - a value, which is no longer valid, because `b` no longer exists. You get an undefined behavior here: the best case scenario is that everything actually will work as you guess it would, the worst case scenario is that you'll get an Access Violation or worse - some data of your program may get corrupted (everything depending on platform and compiler).

Why C++ compiler doesn't notify you about that? Generally because C++ is not supposed to take care of you, such that you won't shoot yourself in the foot (actually, there are so many ways to shoot yourself in the foot using C++, that if you stack books containing these, you would reach Moon). C++ just does what you tell it to. You want to get pointer to `b`? Ok, no problem. You want to return a pointer from function? Why not, that's simply a 32-bit integer value.

The point is, that when writing in C++, you have to be very cautious not to write such code.

---

**Edit:** in response to comments

Imagine, that data is a building and pointer is a piece of paper with address of that building. When you pass pointer by value:

```
void f(int * p)
```

It is like you took another piece of paper and copied the address. If you then erase it and change to another one, the original address on the original piece of paper will remain unchanged.

Now if you do something like:

```
void f(int * p)
{
    *p = 4;
}
```

It's like you actually went to the address written on the piece of paper and changed something in the building. If you then go to the address stored on the original piece of paper, the building will be changed.

Finally, if you do something like:

```
void f(int * & p)
{
}
```

It's like you passed the original piece of paper to the function, so if you change the address, it is changed also outside of the function.

Hope this helps you to understand how pointers work.

Answer (score 2):

C++ functions has **value semantics** , function `f` copies pointer `p1`, original `p1` is not modified.

In `f` function, you tried to point pointer to local variable, this is dangerous.

If you intent to modify pointer `p` points to, you need to pass the address of pointer

```
void f(int*& p) // pass in reference to pointer
{
    static int b = 10;  // make it static, 
                        // so p won't become dangling pointer when f returns
    p = &b;
}
```

Comment: But if I change the function f to 
`void f(int*p){`
    `*p = 4;`
`}`
the original pointer p will change value in the main function!

Answer (score 0):

Here the pointer is passed by value i.e the function f makes a copy of it then uses it, and when it is done it destroys it. the initial pointer p1 is unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

When your pointer becomes invalid, it doesn't magically take on a different or null value. It still points to the same place; it's just that that place is no longer valid.